# Using jquery to create table and select option. How to hide previous table values when option changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I am creating an asset that our sales team and our customers can use to browse through which printer they have and then can see a list of supplies. Once the list is generated I want the customer/salesperson to be able to download the results as a pdf.

I have the code to generate the select options once the brand is selected. I also have the code to generate the Table using jquery and apendTo. My problem is when a different option is selected the previous table values are still there.

I tried making the page reload on the select change but that makes the page not workable and every time an option is selected the page reloads to nothing.

A second problem is the jspdf file I am using is to help stylize the table, but it is creating 2 tables instead of just one?

I have my code in multiple sections so I can keep track of which section is for what. Sorry if it is barbaric looking, I am not well versed in some of this.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0096/5813/8703/t/9/assets/jspdf-autotable@2.3.2.js?13018"></script>
<!--styled pdf<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>


<select name="brand" id="brand" onchange="changecat(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="HP">HP</option>
    <option value="Canon">Canon</option>
    <option value="Mutoh">Mutoh</option>    
</select>
<select name="printers" id="printers" onChange="captioncode()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>

</select>
<br /><br /><br /><br />

<style>
    .PrinterSupplies th,td,tr{
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .PrinterSupplies th{
        font-size:25px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    tbody:last-child::before{
        content:'';
        display:block;
        height:25px;
    }

    .InkSup tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color:rgba(138,189,60,0.15);
    }

    .MediaSup tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: rgba(66,51,82,0.15)
    }
</style>
<!--
This is my test div for the caption id to see if it works.
<div >
    <table class="PrinterSupplies" id="pdfsaver">
        <caption id="printertype"></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="tablehead">Product Name</th>
                <th class="tablehead">Product Sku</th>
                <th class="tablehead">Price</th>
            </tr>       
        </thead>
        <tbody class="InkSup">

            <tr>
                <td>Ink 1</td>
                <td>Ink 1</td>
                <td>Ink 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ink 2</td>
                <td>Ink 2</td>
                <td>Ink 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="MediaSup">
            <tr class="spaceabove">
                <td>Media 1</td>
                <td>Media 1</td>
                <td>Media 1</td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>-->



<br/><br />
<h1>Test Dynamic Table</h1>
<br /><br />
<div id="pdfsaver">
<table class='PrinterSupplies' id='testtest'>
    <caption id='printertype'></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr><th class='tablehead'>Product Name</th>
            <th class='tablehead'>Product Sku</th>
            <th class='tablehead'>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="div" class='InkSup'>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="generate();">Styled PDF</button><button onclick="demoFromHTML();">NonStyled PDF</button>

<script>


    function captioncode() {
        var e = document.getElementById("printers");
        var resulting = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("printertype").innerHTML = resulting + " Supply List";
    };

</script>

<script>

var printersByBrand = {
    HP: ["Select", "HP DesignJet T120", "HP DesignJet T520", "HP DesignJet T730", "HP DesignJet T830 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet T830 36-Inch", "HP DesignJet T930", "HP DesignJet T1530", "HP DesignJet T1600", "HP DesignJet T1700", "HP DesignJet T2530", "HP DesignJet T2600", "HP DesignJet T3500", "HP DesignJet T7200", "HP DesignJet Z6 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6 44-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z9+ 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z9+ 44-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6610 60-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6810 42-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6810 60-Inch"],

    Canon: ["Select", "iPF500", "iPF600", "iPF610", "iPF700", "iPF710", "iPF810", "iPF815", "iPF820", "iPF825", "iPFPro-1000", "iPFPro-2000", "iPFPro-4000", "iPFPro-4000s", "iPFPro-6000s", "iPF5000", "iPF5100", "iPF6000", "iPF6100", "iPF6200", "iPF6300", "iPF6300s", "iPF6350", "iPF6400", "iPF6400s", "iPF6450", "iPF8000", "iPF8000s", "iPF8100", "iPF8300", "iPF8300s", "iPF8400", "iPF8400s", "iPF9000", "iPF9000s", "iPF9100", "iPF9400", "iPF9400s", "iPFW8200", "iPFW8400"],

    Mutoh: ["Select", "Mutoh ValueJet 426UF Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 626UF Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 628 Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1324X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 1624X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 1638X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 2638X Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1627MH Hybrid Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1638UH Hybrid Printer"]
}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("printers").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (printersId in printersByBrand[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option" + " id='" + printersByBrand[value][printersId] + "'>" + printersByBrand[value][printersId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("printers").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    };


</script>

<script>
function generate() {

  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("testtest"));
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {margin: {top: 80}});

  var header = function(data) {
    doc.setFontSize(18);
    doc.setTextColor(40);
    doc.setFontStyle('normal');
      var e = document.getElementById("printers");
      var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
    //doc.addImage(headerImgData, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 20, 50, 50);
    doc.text(result, data.settings.margin.left, 50);
  };

  var options = {
    beforePageContent: header,
    margin: {
      top: 80
    },
    startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20
  };

  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);

  doc.save("table.pdf");
};

</script>

<!--
<script>
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#pdfsaver')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width:700

    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
</script>
-->

<br /><br />


<script>
     var t120Printer = [
        ["HP 711 38-ml Black DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ129A", "$35.98"],
        ["HP 711 29-ml Cyan DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ130A", "$29.92"],
        ["HP 711 29-ml Magenta DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ131A", "$29.92"],
        ["HP 711 29-ml Yellow DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ132A", "$29.92"],
        ["HP 711 80-ml Black DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ133A", "$58.33"],
        ["HP 711 DesignJet Printhead Replacement Kit", "C1Q10A", "$220.24"],
        ["20lb Bond Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "B20IJ24X150", "$9.60"],
        ["20lb White Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "20BIJ24150", "$9.10"],
        ["24lb Premium Coated Bond Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "24IJC24150", "$19.20"],
        ["24lb Premium Coated Bond Paper 24 x 300 (2 inch Core)", "24IJC24300", "$34.47"],
        ["36lb Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "36IJC24100", "$23.40"],
        ["46lb Premium Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "46IJC24100", "$33.46"],
        ["Adhesive Matte Polypropylene 24 x 100 (2 inch core)", "QM-WRPPAD-24", "$60.48"]
     ]
     var t520Printer = [
        ["36lb Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "36IJC24100", "$23.40"],
        ["46lb Premium Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "46IJC24100", "$33.46"],
        ["Adhesive Matte Polypropylene 24 x 100 (2 inch core)", "QM-WRPPAD-24", "$60.48"]
     ]

     var html = ""


    $("#printers").change(function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("printers");
        var resulting = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (resulting == "HP DesignJet T120"){
            $.each(t120Printer, function(rowNum, row){
                console.log(rowNum, row);
                html += "<tr><td>" + row[0] + "<td>" + row[1] + "<td>" + row[2] + "</tr>"
            })

            $((html)).appendTo("#div");
        }
        else if (resulting == "HP DesignJet T520"){
            $.each(t520Printer, function(rowNum, row){
                console.log(rowNum, row);
                html += "<tr><td>" + row[0] + "<td>" + row[1] + "<td>" + row[2] + "</tr>"
            })

            $((html)).appendTo("#div");
        }
        else{
            $((html)).appendTo("#div");
        }

    });


</script>
```

What I would like to happen is when a printer is selected a table is formed and can be downloaded as a PDF. Then when a new printer or brand is selected it removes the previous table values and populates with the new values. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/5abox1d7/

Comment: Have you tried [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)?

Comment: I did try .empty and it either didn't post the information or didn't work?